# Android: gmail app like setting button

Tags: android

You may be familiar with the gmail button on the top left corner of the gmail app for android. And the same button is in google chrome too. Now I am working on an app that have the same button at the same place as the gmail app has. I want to get some help from you people, that how should I start it what should I do for it. Please give me an idea to start it. below is the image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the Google's apps use ActionBar which is the box at the top the application.

Read More:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html